# jQuery get first and last id of multiple classes to var

Tags: jquery

Lets say these are the class divs:

```
<div class="test" id="3">bla</div>
<div class="test" id="4">bla</div>
<div class="test" id="5">bla</div>
<div class="test" id="6">bla</div>
```

How can I get the first id (3) and the last (6) to vars?

```
var firstid = 
var lastid =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selectors, like this:

```
var firstid = $(".test:first").attr("id");
var lastid = $(".test:last").attr("id");
```

If you want to get a number, instead of a string, do this:

```
var firstid = parseInt($(".test:first").attr("id"));
var lastid = parseInt($(".test:last").attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var firstid = $('.test:first-of-type').attr('id');
var lastid = $('.test:last-of-type').attr('id');
```

or

```
var firstid = $('.test').eq(0).attr('id');
var lastid = $('.test').eq(3).attr('id');
```

or

```
var firstid = $('.test').first().attr('id');
var lastid = $('.test').last().attr('id');
```

Comment: I get "undefined" from the lastid